# Storing input with space in multiple variable

Tags: c++

I would like to know how to split up user input and store it into multiple variable.

```
char firstname[100];

char lastname[100];

cout <<"Please enter your full name ";
```

lets say they enter "bob eric" I would like to store "bob" in firstname variable and store "eric" in lastname variable, and the delimeter is alwasy a space.

Comment: you use operator>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently using the output stream operator to display the prompt. There is an equivalent input stream operator that takes input from the console. I would recommend changing your C strings into C++ `std::string`s as they are less error prone. You could do something like this:

```
std::string firstname;
std::string lastname;

std::cout <<"Please enter your full name ";
std::cin >> firstname;
std::cin >> lastname;
```